# YAMAHA RTX 1210 router VPN(multiple user) connection error

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I recently tried YAMAHA router(for VPN purposes) RTX 1210 but there seems to be a problem with my setting.

Problem:
Also this is displaying when a second person is trying to connect to it:

The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer could not negotiate compatible parameters with the remote computer.
After trying show log command following results show:

> PP[ANONYMOUS01] Call detected from user 'USERNAME'
> PP[ANONYMOUS01] PPP/IPV6CP up
> PP[ANONYMOUS01] PPP/IPCP up (Local:[Gate way IP address], Remote : [Remote address pool IP])
> [IKE] respond ISAKMP phase to [ISP static IP]
> [IKE] respond IPsec phase to [ISP static IP]
> [IKE] initiate info exchange (notification)
> [IKE] initiate informational exchange (delete)